# how to draw a line on clicking a button using applet

Tags: java, event-handling, awt

I m a beginner in java and encountered a problem in drawing lines in applet using a
    button click.Please help me in resolving this.
    p.s.-I don't know swing or other advanced part.
It is drawing concurrent lines, also on maximizing the applet only the last drawn line is visible. please help with this problem too.On clicking at another point the previously drawn lines disappear. I want to make a program which draw lines on clicking a button and they shouldn't disappear.

```
//program to draw lines
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/*
<applet code=xy width=200 height=200>
</applet>
*/
public class xy extends Applet implements MouseListener,ActionListener
{   Button b;
int x1, y1,x2,y2;

    public void init()
{b=new Button();    
add(b);     
x1=y1=x2=y2=0;
b.addActionListener(this);
}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
    if(ae.getSource()==b) //button click
    {
addMouseListener(this);
    }}

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) 
{
x1=me.getX();
y1=me.getY();
showStatus( "(" + x1 + "," + y1+ ")" ); 
}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
{}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me)
{
x2=me.getX();
y2=me.getY();
repaint();
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me)
    {}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me)
{}


    public void paint(Graphics g)
{
update(g);
}

    public void update(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawLine( x1,y1,x2,y2);
}}
```

Comment: Please format and indent your code properly. And respect the Java naming conventions. You're asking us to read your code. Make it readable.

Comment: @JBNizet I copied the code as it is.I already mentioned that m a beginner so, m learning. Thanks for your advice but if i can understand n read this code then you being an expert can easily read this.

Comment: Sure. I can pee in disgusting, dirty toilets as well. But if you invite me in your house, you'll try to make your toilets clean, won't you? Then do the same with your code. If you ask people to read your code, make sure it's well-formatted and indented, and respects the naming conventions. You're asking for help, for free. If you're not ready to make a small effort, why would we?

Comment: Mr. whatever u r. Go and use ur valueable time somewhere else(in ur loo coz u need it badly) rather than wasting ur time here teaching ethics to others.If u can't read it then just DON'T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the lines by yourself and draw all stored lines again on each repaint of the applet. (see also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html if you want to use JApplet instead of applet)